# Google Autocomplete - how to fetch information about the loaded address?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places

I have an input where a user enters his location. From this location, I want to fetch city, state and zip and enter these information into another inputs (inputs for city, state and zip), so the user doesn't need to fill these information manually.

I found an example of what I am trying to achieve [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) and trying to modify it to my needs.

So here I go:

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete_origin_address, autocomplete_destination_address;
var componentForm_origin = {
  user_origin_city: 'user_origin_city',
  user_origin_state: 'user_origin_state',
  user_origin_zip: 'user_origin_zip'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  console.log('in "initAutocomplete"');
  autocomplete_origin_address = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    document.getElementById('user_origin_address'), 
                            types: ['geocode']}
  );
  autocomplete_origin_address.addListener("place_changed",
                                         fillInAddress(autocomplete_origin_address, 
                                                      "user_origin_address",
                                                      "user_origin_city", 
                                                      "user_origin_state",
                                                      "user_origin_zip"));

}

function fillInAddress(autocomplete_resource, address, city, state, zip) {
  console.log("! !x");
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete_resource.getPlace();

  // origin fields to populate with the selected address
  var fetched_street_number = fetchAddressDetails(place, "street_number", "long_name");

  var fetched_address = fetchAddressDetails(place, "route", "long_name");
  $("#"+address).val(fetched_street_number + " " + address);

  var fetched_city = fetchAddressDetails(place, "locality", "long_name");
  $("#"+city).val(fetched_city);

  var fetched_state = fetchAddressDetails(place, "administrative_area_level_1", "short_name");
  $("#"+state).val(fetched_state);

  var fetched_zip = fetchAddressDetails(place, "postal_code", "long_name");
  $("#"+zip).val(fetched_zip);
}

function fetchAddressDetails(autocomplete_place, detail_type, name_type){
  console.log("in fetchAddressDetails");
  var item = $.grep(autocomplete_place.address_components, 
                    function(e){ return e.types[0] == detail_type; });
  var item_data = item[0][name_type];
  console.log("item_data: "+item_data);
  return item_data;                                                     
}

initAutocomplete();
```

But when I load the page, I get this error:

```
in "initAutocomplete"
! !x
in fetchAddressDetails
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'address_components' of undefined
```

I am trying to google the issue, but cannot get rid of it and make it code work.
What I am generally trying - I have 4 inputs on the page, where users enter the address.
So I want - when the enter an address to each of those 4 inputs - ruby the google autocomplete functionality, fetch the address and put the city/state/zip information to the respective inputs.

Can you advise, please, why it currently doesn't fetch anything?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue, including any required HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just a typo, but there is a syntax error that could be causing the problem...

```
types: ['geocode']} // <~~ missing it's opening curly brace..!
```

should read...

```
{types: ['geocode']}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Billy, it's just a typo though (happened when I was formatting the code here on SO).